# Is the following set in $\mathbb R^2$ connected?

Tags: connectedness, proof-verification

> Is the following set in $\mathbb R^2$ connected?: $A=\{(x, y) : x^2y^2 = 1\}$

*My attempt:* $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R:(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is continuous and $f(A)=\{-1,1\}.$ Since $f(A)$ is disconnected so is $A.$

Please tell me if it's correct or not.

Comment: If we're picky, you need to prove that $f(A) = \{-1,1\}$, say by observing $\{(1,-1),(1,1)\} \subset A$. But aside from that, your proof is correct and elegant.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cut down on un-answered questions, I'll simply make Daniel Fischer's comment an answer.

"If we're picky, you need to prove that $f(A)=\{-1,1\},$ say by observing $\{(1,-1),(1,1)\}\subset A.$ But aside from that, your proof is correct and elegant."